# Order of zero in $\mathbb{Z}_m$

Tags: group-theory, arithmetic, integers

Would it be correct to say that the order of zero in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ under addition is infinite?

And if it's infinite then there can be no bijection between a dihedral group and $\mathbb{Z}_m$?

Comment: If you have a group $G$, then $1_G$ has order 1. Now, $0$ is the identity element of $\mathbb{Z}_m$, so its order is 1.

Comment: Think of order as the *least* positive integer $n$ such that $a^n = e$. In your case, $a = 0 = e$, so $n=1$.

Comment: Right. For some reason I "assumed" that 1 is the identity (confused), whereas it's zero under addition.

Answer (score 2):

The order of an element $g$ is the least positive integer $k$ such that $g^k=e$ (using multiplicative notation).  In your case $\underbrace{0}_{1~\text{time}} = 0$ so it is order $1$

Compare this to, say, the element $4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ where $\underbrace{4+4+4}_{3~\text{times}}=0$ so the order of $4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}=3$

Answer (score 2):

The order of an element $g$ is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $kg=0$. In this case the smallest such $k$ is $1$.

Another way to define order is as the order of the subgroup generated by $g$, denoted $\langle g \rangle $. In this case $\langle 0 \rangle=\{0\}$ which has order $1$.